# PDO: Select, Insert, Delete, Update

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Вот возник такой вопросик с раздела **PDO** в **php**. Я знаю, что:

```
$db->query(''); //Используется для SELECT
$db->prepare(''); //Используется для INSERT и UPDATE
$db->exec(''); //Используется для DELETE
```

Но у меня шило в одном месте и я пробовал `query` для каждого метода и она работало. Стоит ли так делать? И еще один такой вопросик, для чего нужен `execute()` заранее спасибо

Comment: >> пробовал query для каждого метода и она работало

да работать то оно будет. тут разделение не на update/insert, а на то, что подготовленный запрос (prepare) фильтрует входные данные. даже при селекте его стоит использовать. с query лучше выполнять только 100% безопасный запрос, например, в котором нет никаких подстановок.

Comment: @Heleg, Ого, это много геморая при каждом запросе)

Comment: в чем тут гемморой, просто интересно?
без prepare ещё больше геммороя (всякие mysql_escape_string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Боже мой...

> PDO::query — Выполняет SQL запрос и возвращает результирующий набор в виде объекта PDOStatement
>
> PDO::prepare — Подготавливает запрос к выполнению и возвращает ассоциированный с этим запросом объект
>
> PDO::exec — Запускает SQL запрос на выполнение и возвращает количество строк, задействованых в ходе его выполнения

**[ЧИТАТЬ ДАЛЕЕ...](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)**

Comment:  я сам всегда юзаю query. А execute вроде как просто не возвращает результат(точно не знаю).

Comment: Ок, я понял, спасибо.